# Boolean Modifier (Difference) Issue Persists Even After Applying All Transformations, Recalcing Normals, and Fixing Non-Manifolds

Tags: modifiers

I've been wrestling with this issue for the past couple of hours. Here's the gist of it (version 2.8):

I'm trying to "shave off" a piece of my mesh, and have a designated "knife" object. I intend on using the boolean modifier for this. Before using the modifier, I made sure both objects were water tight with correctly facing normals. I also applied all transformations. Yet, I still have an issue.

After applying the modifier, the "knife" object only "traces out" the pieces of the mesh that I wanted to cut, and does not actually delete the intended vertices.

I've included a YouTube link to a 1-min video that describes what I'm talking about (https://bit.ly/337UaC6).

Here's also a link to the actual blender file: [image]

I've also included some pictures of my "main" object:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please let me know if I need to provide anything else. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have here unconnected meshes (and possibly overlapping). Try to perform boolean operation on each part of mesh separately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What part of the mesh are you suspecting is unconnected?

Comment: @SergeL I checked my main mesh again—it was fully manifold with no overlaps/ disconnects. I also tried to boolean each portion of my mesh separately, but the same issue still persists.

Comment: Share a file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com for easier investigation

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6749" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6749/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are were inverted normals, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate them.
2. Overlapping edges between boolean cutter and source object. This is healed by moving edge away from the cut. It's a front view: yellow edge is source, white is cutter:

   [image]
3. Lots of ngons, so consider doing retopology. I added *Triangulate* modifier to make it more boolean-friendly:

   [image]

Also keep boolean object's geometry as simple as posible, avoid excessive edges which doesn't contribute to final shape.

[image]

Comment: Holy crap! Thank you! Didn't know about the Triangulate modifier.